# Swift - Parse - How to loop into PFObject attributes

Tags: json, swift, parse-platform, null

I'm getting a JSON where some attributes can or cannot be available. So I decode those fields as a nil value.

Parser doesn't accept nil as a value but NSNULL.

After preparing my PFObject like :

```
let object = PFObject(classname: "Foo")
object["Bar1"] = self.bar1
object["Bar2"] = self.bar2
[...]
```

If I try :

```
for item in object {
            if item == nil {
                item = NSNULL
            }
        }
```

I got this error:

```
Type 'PFObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

Comment: As error indicates you can't iterate attributes of a PFObject like that. You need to explicitly check all vars and do the check.

Comment: Are you aware that parse it shutting down? Building something that runs on parse at the moment is not the best idea as it will be getting shut down soon

Comment: As @Shripada has indicated, PFObject is not a collection type and thus cannot be iterated. In addition, Parse.com is shutting down but the parse-server is available to be self-hosted. Refer: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Comment: @Eli : are you aware that you can build your own parse server ? ;)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04.

So I have to do a thousand of if. OK... thanks...

Comment: OMFG i didnt know that haha i have an entire app that i was working on cheers! Now i can finish it

Comment: @Santhosh : can you put your comment as a respond so I can validate it as the good answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shripada has indicated, PFObject is not a collection type and thus cannot be iterated. In addition, Parse.com is shutting down but the parse-server is available to be self-hosted. Refer: [github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)